# Python console not working at all

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-2.4

My python console won't work at all. I can't open it.
My QGIS version is 2.4. OS is win7 64.
I've reinstalled QGIS a few times but I always get the same result. 
Strange. Something went wrong with the source code I guess?
Here's the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in    File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 43, in
 show_console
     _console = PythonConsole( parent )   File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 75, in
 __init__
     self.console = PythonConsoleWidget(self)   File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 101, in
 __init__
     self.shellOut = ShellOutputScintilla(self)   File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_output.py", line 103,
 in __init__
     self.insertInitText()   File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_output.py", line 145,
 in insertInitText
     socket.gethostname()) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128) Version de
 Python :
 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] Version de QGIS :
 2.4.0-Chugiak 'Chugiak', 8fdd08a Chemin vers Python : ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing',
```

Comment: socket.gethostname() returns the name you (or your administrator) have given your computer. This must be english letters. Try to change your computers name to only include english letters.

Answer (score 1):

socket.gethostname() returns the name you (or your administrator) have given your computer. This must be english letters (ASCII). Try to change your computers name to only include english letters.

Comment: Thank's a lot Jakob. You saved my day! It works perfectly now. I was wondering how it worked with other languages (chinese, arabic,..). Can it not be set to python to use UTF8?

Comment: Not sure it is possibly in Python 2.7 with socket.gethostname(). I used to be a C# developer enjoying danish letters, now working with Python 2.7 half of my time goes with sorting stuff like this out. May not, myself, have seen the light yet...